# assert_select expectation contradicting itself (ruby)

Tags: ruby, assert, minitest, assertions, assertion

This is the code in my test:

```
assert_select "a[href=?]", "/path/with?params", { :count => 1, :text => "" }
```

And this is the failure message I get:

```
Expected exactly 1 element matching "a[href='/path/with?params']", found 0..
Expected: 0
Actual: 1
```

Any clues what's happening here? Is it expecting 0 or 1 and is it finding 1 or 0?

**UPDATE:** For everyone coming here searching how to do what I was trying to do, I ended up doing this:

`assert_match(/<a href="/path/with?params">/, response.body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known problem.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14422

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14450